# Unable to load Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I get this error everytime I try to load colab. It pops up in a window and I'm not able to display my previous files, and if I want to work on a new notebook it won't let me insert code cells etc. I'm using Chrome as browser.

Error Message:

```
Unable to load Colaboratory.
 DETAILS
Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Does this issue reproduce in an incognito window with all extensions disabled? (Extensions are a common cause of this sort of problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you some ways to solve this problem :

**1 -** Go to your Google Drive and you will see Folder called "Colab Notebooks" , Delete it from your drive. Close your browser and open it again and open Google drive again and create folder called "Colab Notebooks" then go to Colab and it must work with you.

**2 -** Sometimes types of browser cause Errors , Try to use Firefox instead of chrome.

**3 -** open Colab in "incognito mode".
If still have problem , comment below and will help ASAP.
Wish you all the best.